# Automorphisms of Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

This is a questions I've been playing with the last few days:

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple graph with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$. We will denote the vertex-deleted induced subgraph obtained by deleting $v\in V$ as $G_v$. Given two vertices $x,y\in V$ such that $G_x\cong G_y$, when does an isomorphism $\phi:G_x\rightarrow G_y$ extend to an automorphism, $\tilde{\phi}:G\rightarrow G$?

First thought: it would seem that the structure of such a graph would have some sort of symmetry described by and action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on $\{x,y\}\subset V$ (i.e. there is a map $\psi(x)=y$ that extends to an automorphism on $G$). This is based on intuition an may be completely wrong.

Comment: If the isomorphism does not extend, the vertices are said to pseudo-similar, and there is some literature. For fine regular graphs, the isomorphism always extends. I do not recall any signs of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in this situation.

Comment: Perhaps my idea regarding $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is too restrictive - I seem to be thinking of some sort of vertex transitivity. I will have to work to formulate this precisely and post as a separate question after I can work on it bit. Maybe what is more interesting is looking at the obstruction to similarity (i.e. x and y lying in the same orbit and hence having isomorphic vertex deleted subgraphs)?

Comment: @ChrisGodsil I think I've put together the thought I was rambling about in my previous comment. We can partition the vertex set, $V=\displaystyle\cup_{i=1}^k V_i$ such that $x,y\in V_i$ if and only if $G_x\cong G_y$. Maximally, $Aut(G)$ acts transitively on $V_i$. I'm not sure is the interplay between the way $Aut(G)$ acts on these sets is well studied but it would seem relevant in finding obstructions to $Aut(G)$ acting transitively.